# Search the list values in a csv file and return the other column value in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a list that contains integer values as follows

```
mylist = [2, 10, 5]
```

Now I want to find the elements in 'mylist' in a csv file shown below and return the 'item_code' attached to it.

```
No, item_code
1, nm111
2, nm121
3, nm131
4, nm141
```

I am currently doing it using csv as follows.

```
with open('item_codes.csv', 'r') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
     for row in reader:
         if row[0] in mylist:
```

However, I am interested in doing this in pandas as well. Please help me.

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('item_codes.csv'); print(df[df.No.isin(mylist)].item_code)`.

Comment: are `mylist` and `paper_numbers` the same variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put the csv data into a dataframe like this :

```
df = pd.read_csv('item_codes.csv')
print(df)
```

output:

```
No, item_code
1, nm111
2, nm121
3, nm131
4, nm141
```

#### Option 1:

You could do the following:

```
df[df["No"].isin([2, 10, 5])]["item_code"].tolist()
```

which will give you a list of all the `item_code` values in the same row as  the integers from the list `[2, 10, 5]`

#### Option 2:

As suggested by @jezrael in the comments below we can also use `df.loc`.

*Explanation:* Since `df["No"].isin([2, 10, 5])` returns an array of booleans, we can use this array as a mask to select the rows and get the same results as follows:

```
df.loc[df["No"].isin([2, 10, 5]),"item_code"].tolist()
```

Comment: better is loc like `df.loc[df["No"].isin([2, 10, 5]), "item_code"].tolist() `

Comment: what happens with loc?

Comment: @jezrael yes! I'll update my answer to cover that as well.

Comment: loc select column `item_code`. I once timed it and it is faster.